# How to get the git repository that I cloned before?

Tags: git, github

After cloning a git repository, How can I get the repository file?

for example)

After "git clone http://sunglim@github.com/asdf/asdf.git"

I want to know the URL(http://sunglim@github.com/asdf/asdf.git).

how can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `remote show`, although it's gonna ask your key:

```
git remote show origin | grep 'Fetch URL'
```

Comment: To avoid being asked for the key, use `-n` option.

Answer (score 6):

If you look in .git/config there should be a block similar to the following:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = ...
    url = <this is the url you want>
```

You can get this from the command line using

```
git config --get remote.origin.url
```

Hope that gets what you want.